# What is the ideal way to disable and hide a UIButton / UIBarButtonItem?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, storyboard

In my app, if it is run for the first time or the user has cleared their login credentials, a view is presented modally in which they can login. They can also optionally show the login view if they wish to switch accounts. However, I also want them to be able to dismiss this view with a “Cancel” button if they mistakenly tapped the “Switch Account” button, but not if the app is running for the first time.

I know I can do this by making a `UIBarButtonItem` in code and setting its `hidden` and `enabled` properties, but was wondering if it was possible using Storyboards and Outlets. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can do that. You just address the hidden or enabled messages to the outlet. So, if you have an IBOutlet called myButton that is connected to a button in IB, you write:

```
myButton.hidden = YES;
```

Comment: Will this disable a UIBarButtonItem too?

Comment: @duci9y, you can disable it with myButton.enabled = NO, but there is no hidden property for bar button items. You can remove it, by setting it to nil (for example, self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;)